# cannot type in iframe on ipad

Tags: ipad, iframe

I have an interactive crossword on a [webpage](http://historyofliverpool.com/crosswords/?puzzle=war-of-the-roses-crossword), that works fine on an ipad:

However, when this page is inserted into an iframe ([here](http://historyofliverpool.com/war-roses-crossword-ks3-history/)), although the ipad acknoleges screen taps and brings up the keyboard, it does not put the letters typed on screen (i.e in  the crossword.)

Basically, how can I alter the iframe or page code to work 100% on an ipad and actually allow me to enter text??

Comment: I've seen people complain about this issue for quite a while. It's documented here: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2523403 and here: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues/51